# Earth vs. aliens, long war ends in secret mutual surrender

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'd like your help in identifying an SF book I read many many years ago.

I don't remember the title or author, but the premise was that there had been a long war between earth and an alien planet, and finally the leaders of both groups got together and decided, secretly, to each surrender to the other side, so that under foreign occupation the leaders could commit sanctioned "atrocities", which would actually be "necessary" population control and clean-up.

Comment: Oy ... I know I've read this novel, but I too cannot place the author or title off the top of my head.  I'm moving soon and all my 600+ Sci Fi novels are packed.  If its the one I'm thinking of its likely 1980s or 1990s Sci Fi.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193259/novel-about-interstellar-war-both-sides-win-both-sides-think-they-lost

Answer (score 4):

In [this Usenet thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf.written/7lCJStS2v7Y) Ted Nolan has identified the book as [*Triple Detente*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12755) by [Piers Anthony](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?4). That identification appears to be correct. Here is a description from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879971304):

> Earth and Kazo have created a unique peace. Kazo administers Earth, and Earth controls Kazo. Nothing is really complicated until both humans and Kazos discover the existence of a third intelligent race in the galaxy and try to bring them into the newly developing peace.